# ESRI Basemaps - World Imagery: Is it possible to bring certain imagery into foreground (change the viewing order)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, imagery, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have a basemap loaded in a map in which there are 4 overlapping images.  I would like to either turn off 3 of the 4 images or bring the one i want (marked with X n the screen capture) into the foreground.  Is this possible? Is there a workaround?

I tried un-checking lower resolution layers in the TOC but a messages pops up saying that thisis not possible. 
[image]

Comment: I don't believe you can. ESRI controls the setup of the basemap layer, and it's configured to show the highest available resolution for any given area at a particular zoom. I'm guessing your desired source is a lower resolution than the other four available to the tiling. The only workaround I can see would be to identify that image source and either get it directly or see if there is another map (ie through ArcGIS Online) that is *just* that image source.